# How to count square matrix represented as vectors in clojure

Tags: vector, clojure

Assume that a two-dimensional matrix is represented as a vector of
vectors, such that the innermost vectors each represent a row in the
matrix . A two-dimensional matrix is square if the number of rows is equal
to the number of columns.

Answer (score 3):

Why the loop-recur constraint?

If you can assume every row is the same size (regular structure), this would work:

```
(defn is-square [m]
  (= (count m) (count (first m))))
```

If you want to check every row:

```
(defn is-square [m]
  (apply = (count m) (map count m)))
```

If you really really want to use loop-recur for some reason:

```
(defn is-square [m]
  (loop [[row & more] m]
    (if row
      (if (= (count row) (count m))
        (recur more)
        false)
      true)))
```

Comment: I'd rewrite the `apply` version as `(defn is-square [m] (apply = (count m) (map count m)))`.

Comment: Well. This is for tutorial purpose to demonstrate to students how it works from different approaches. Can also tell how this can be done using both map and reduce instead of just map. Thanks

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena yes, better. changed.